# delete and copy files using shx in package.json

Tags: node.js, unix, npm, gatsby, npm-scripts

I have two npm projects, one is a [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) project called `web-project` and another one is [Express](https://expressjs.com/) project called `server-project`.

This is the file structure of the projects:

```
- projects
   - web-project
      - public
      - package.json
   - server-project
      - package.json
      - public
```

If I run command `npm run build` in `web-project/package.json`, I would like to generate build files for web-project, delete content in folder `server-project/public` and copy content from `web-project/public` to `server-project/public`.

I tried to use [shx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx), which is installed locally in `web-project`, but it doesn't work. Gatsby generates build files, but shx doesn't copy them.

**web-project/package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build && (shx find ../server-project/public -type f -delete && shx cp -R public/* ../server-project/public)"
    ...
  },
```

npm debug log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.1.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle tau@1.0.0~prebuild: tau@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: tau@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/and/devel/tau/web-project/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: CWD: /Users/and/devel/tau/web-project
10 silly lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'gatsby build && (shx find ../server-project/public -type ' +
10 silly lifecycle     'f -delete && shx cp -R public/* ../server-project/public)'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: tau@1.0.0 build: `gatsby build && (shx find ../server-project/public -type f -delete && shx cp -R public/* ../server-project/public)`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
14 verbose pkgid tau@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/and/devel/tau/web-project
16 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.1.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error tau@1.0.0 build: `gatsby build && (shx find ../server-project/public -type f -delete && shx cp -R public/* ../server-project/public)`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the tau@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried to change build command to only copy files from one folder to another folder:

**web-project/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tau",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "shx cp -R public/* ../server-project/public",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "gh-pages": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public",
    "lint": "eslint src --fix",
    "dev": "(shx --silent rm -rf public .cache || shx true) && gatsby develop",
    "server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development DEBUG=api nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "PI",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.7",
    "@kunukn/react-collapse": "1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.3.3",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "basic-auth": "^2.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.2.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "d3-node": "^2.2.1",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "framer-motion": "^1.10.3",
    "gatsby": "^2.18.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls": "^2.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-dark-mode": "^1.1.0",
    "gatsby-source-prismic-graphql": "^3.5.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.6.53",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.pickby": "^4.6.0",
    "marked": "^0.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prismic-reactjs": "^1.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.8.0",
    "react-collapsible": "^2.6.3",
    "react-d3-components": "^0.9.1",
    "react-d3-library": "^1.1.8",
    "react-headroom": "^3.0.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.6.5",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.6",
    "react-onclickout": "^2.0.8",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.3",
    "react-popper-tooltip": "^2.11.1",
    "react-responsive": "^8.0.1",
    "react-scroll-to": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "react-sidebar": "^3.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.25.2",
    "react-svg-donuts": "^1.0.0",
    "react-telegram-embed": "^0.0.10",
    "react-toastify": "^5.4.1",
    "react-twitter-embed": "^3.0.3",
    "react-window": "^1.8.5",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "yarn": "^1.21.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prototype-interactive/eslint-config": "^0.1.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.4.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^2.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss-sass": "^1.0.22",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.0.7",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.2.2",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "^2.1.7",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.8.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "shx": "^0.3.2",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/PI/gatsby-react-boilerplate.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/PI/gatsby-react-boilerplate/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/PI/gatsby-react-boilerplate#readme"
}
```

npm debug log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.1.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle tau@1.0.0~prebuild: tau@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: tau@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/and/devel/tau/web-project/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: CWD: /Users/and/devel/tau/web-project
10 silly lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'shx cp -R public/* ../web-project-project/public' ]
11 silly lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle tau@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: tau@1.0.0 build: `shx cp -R public/* ../web-project-project/public`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
14 verbose pkgid tau@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/and/devel/tau/web-project
16 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.1.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error tau@1.0.0 build: `shx cp -R public/* ../web-project-project/public`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the tau@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Remove `--silent` and then try, so that at least error can be seen

Comment: @TarunLalwani I removed `--silent` and updated question with new log file

Comment: Did you try to break it into parts? First run `gatsby build` and then the 2 `shx` commands independently to see what you get? Also, do you have `shx` installed globally or locally?

Comment: As @ChristosLytras mentioned you need to break the commands into 3 commands and run them one by one to understand which command actually is breaking. It may be the build itself.

Comment: @ChristosLytras shx is installed locally and yes, I did try to break command into parts, but the error message is not helpful. I edited my question and added npm log file.

Comment: @TarunLalwani shx command is breaking.

Comment: @Matt please add your full `package.json` contents. I see there are `prebuild` and `postbuild` scripts that trigger `node-gyp` for some reason and a rebuild regarding a `tau` package? (*`verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]`*)

Comment: @ChristosLytras thanks for your reply. I added complete `package.json` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue exists in this part:

```json
shx find ../server-project/public -type f -delete
```

The `-type f` flag is not supported in `shx` (see [issue #177](https://github.com/shelljs/shx/issues/177)). Presumably, the `-delete` flag is also not supported.

Consider replacing that part with a node.js script that does the following:

1. Utilizes the [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) [`find`](https://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs#findpath--path-) method.
2. Iterates the Array of found pathnames using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
3. In the body of the `forEach` callback checks whether it's a file and deletes accordingly.

For instance, putting it altogether into a single npm script named `build`:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "gatsby build && node -e \"var sh = require('shelljs'), fs = require('fs'); sh.find('../server-project/public').forEach(function (file) { if (!fs.statSync(file).isDirectory()) { sh.rm(file); }});\" && shx cp -R \"public\" \"../server-project/public\""
  ...
}
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Your attempted usage of `find ../server-project/public -type f -delete` in your OP implies that your intention is to delete all files (only) from `../server-project/public` (*n* levels deep) - but don't delete any folders in `../server-project/public` (again *n* levels deep). This is what the `node -e \"...\"` command in the aforementioned example replicates.
2. The nodejs command line option [`-e`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) is utilized to evaluate the inline Javascript, which is essentially this:

   ```js
   var sh = require('shelljs'),
       fs = require('fs');

   sh.find('../server-project/public').forEach(function (file) {
       if (!fs.statSync(file).isDirectory()) {
           sh.rm(file);
       }
   });
   ```

   - As you can see, a combination of the [Logical NOT (`!`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) operator, the [`fs.statSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path_options) method and [`isDirectory()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_stats_isdirectory) are utilized to ascertain whether the pathname is a file and not a directory/folder.
   - The file is deleted using the shelljs [`rm`](https://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs#rmoptions-file--file-) method.
3. The globstar (`*`) in your final `shx cp -R ...` command, and the parentheses `(...)` encasing the compound commands, have been omitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the wildcard from `shx cp -R public/* ../server-project/public`, as the recursive flag will pick up everything in the source directory. This should get you what you are after -

```
shx cp -R public ../server-project/public
```

Comment: Thanks, I found out that this command fails `find ../server-project/public -type f -delete`. I tried just simply `shx rm ../server-project/public/*` and it fails too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are already using `find` in your build system.  I leverage tar and find heavily in some of the build systems I maintain, and this works well for me.  tar handles a really wide variety of edge cases very nicely, since it was originally written as a backup utility.

in tar, - is the filename that means stdin or stdout, -T specifies the list of files to backup, and -C specifies its working directory. This lets you glue a bunch of stuff together with the pipeline and some pretty cool stuff done. For example,

```
(cd /path/to/src/files && find . -type f -name) \
| tar -T - -cf - \
| tar -C /path/to/dest -xvf -
```

- The subshell lets me the directory for find without affecting other commands
- find produces a list of files on stdout
- the first tar reads the list of files to archive on stdin
- the first tar produces the archive on stdout
- the second tar changes directory to /path/to/dest
- then it extracts the archive on stdin
- and 'v' prints the list of files it is extract while it does it

This will preserve ownership, group membership, permissions, symlinks, directory structure, the whole nine yards for you.  Even filenames with spaces won't mess it up. :)

Comment: Interesting. I found out that this command fails `find ../server-project/public -type f -delete`. I tried just simply `shx rm ../server-project/public/*` and it fails too.